# How to prevent Maven from downloading artifacts from repository when I just update the pom version of my project

Tags: maven, repository, pom.xml, artifactory

I'm using Maven as CI and JFrog Artifactory as a repository of my own artifacts and as a cache. Everything works fine. I'm using the Artifactory plugin in Jenkins to trigger artifact download and upload.
I cannot figure how to handle the following use case.

I have a multi-module project. In my Settings.xml I defined some snapshot, plugin, and release repositories.

In my local workspace, I upgraded the pom version of the parent project and its children. Then I made a local clean install. It failed because Maven was trying to download the artifacts of my project from Artifactory and they don't exist of course because I'm trying to create a new version of the project.

How to handle this use case? How to configure my pom or settings to do?
How to do this in the Artifactory plugin in Jenkins in a freestyle way?

I have error messages like this:

> 10:23:28 Failed to transfer Could not find metadata com.xxx.xxxx.xxx:my-parent-project:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in xxx
> 10:23:50 [FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for com.xxx.xxxx.xxx:subpoject1:[unknown-version]: Could not find artifact .....and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 7, column 10*

=====================================

pom configuration of the parent pom

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
<artifactId>my-parent-project</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>


<modules>
    <module>../subproject-1</module>
    <module>../subproject-2</module>
</modules>
```

==================================

pom configuration for subproject1

```
    <artifactId>subproject-1</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-parent-project</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

======================================

Here is my settings.xml configuration

```
<profile>
        <id>artifactory_profile</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>libs-release</name>
                <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots />
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
            </repository>

            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>sing</id>
                <name>sing-virtual-repo</name>
                <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:8081/artifactory/virtual-repo</url>
            </repository>               
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>central</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
            <pluginRepository>
                <snapshots />
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <name>plugins-release</name>
                <url>http://xxxxxxxxxxxx:8081/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run `clean install` on the parent POM, then everything will be created correctly.

Comment: Thank you. That what I'm doing. I run mvn clean install within the parent pom directory. By googling, I found that in the settings.xml we can define **updatePolicy** for snapshots and releases. So I set updatePolcy to always for releases, and never for snapshots and deleted all the artifacts and run again clean install. It works. The only problem for me, is that I have some external dependencies that are snapshots so I cannot  set the policy fto **never** all the time.

Comment: This works independently of the update policy.

Comment: Anonther question/  I have the same settings.xml in my jenkins config. And even if disable the Artifactory plugin for my job, and do a clean install I still have a problem :

Comment: Please ask a new question on Stackoverflow.